# ONLYOFFICE when url and callbackUrl have diffent [example.com]

Tags: onlyoffice

{
"document": {
"fileType": "docx",
"key": "Khirz6zTPdfd7",
"permissions": {
"download": true,
"edit": true,
"print": true,
"review": true
},
"title": "Example Document Title.docx",
**"url":** "https://aaaa.com/url-to-example-document.docx"
},
"editorConfig": {
**"callbackUrl"**: "https://bbbb.com/url-to-callback.ashx",
"mode": "edit",
"user": {
"group": "Group1",
"id": "78e1e841",
"name": "Smith"
}
}
}
//when zhe  url and callbackUrl are different ,zhe url is the oss file,but zhe callbackUrl is my //site,when i edited,my callbackUrl cant receive any request,but when i open i can receive.

Answer (score 0):

{
"document": {
"fileType": "docx",
"key": "Khirz6zTPdfd7",
"permissions": {
"download": true,
"edit": true,
"print": true,
"review": true
},
"title": "Example Document Title.docx",
"url": "https://example.com/url-to-example-document.docx"
},
"editorConfig": {
"callbackUrl": "https://example.com/url-to-callback.ashx",
"mode": "edit",
"user": {
"group": "Group1",
"id": "78e1e841",
"name": "Smith"
}
}
}`json`